# Inserting array into SQL Server database problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, arrays, insert

I'm attempting to insert an array into a SQL Server database. 1/4 is copied to the database before I receive the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 's'. Unclosed
>   quotation mark after the character
>   string ', ')'.

Here is the button click event -

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("server=localhost; uid=xxxx; pwd=xxxx; database=Movies;");
   sql.Open();

   for (int i = 0; i < jointArray.Length; i++)
   {
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [" + folderName + "] " + "values('" + jointArray[i].ToString() +"', '')", sql);
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }

   sql.Close();
}
```

Comment: The problem is surely linked to the content of the array, can you please give us some information about it ?

Comment: How do you know that 1/4 is executed successfully? Also, as Krtek has mentioned, there would most probably be a function in `SqlCommand` class to dump the query to output. If you check that it might solve your problem OR paste it in your question.

Comment: 130 movie names are getting copied to the database from which is approx 1/4 of the total from the selected directory

Comment: Have you ever heard of [SQL injection attacks??](http://xkcd.com/327/) - don't concatenate together your SQL statements!! Use **parametrized queries** instead - **ALWAYS**

Comment: Why don't you use a parameterized query? this way you would get rid of the string manipulation that seems to cause problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that a 1/4 of the way through jointArray[i].ToString() contains an apostrophe.

So instead of a SQL query that looks like this..

```
insert into [MyFolder] values('MyValue')
```

you end up with something that looks like this

```
insert into [MyFolder] values('MyValue's')
```

which causes the error (notice where incorrect syntax near the s is!)

Please consider using parameters with your SQLCommand (look up `Parameters.Add` and `Parameters.AddWithValue`).

Using Parameters makes your code

- More readable
- Easier to debug
- Less prone to SQL injection attacks (which recently got Sony Pictures hacked)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you might have apostrophes in your data, which is messing up your query.

This is a really bad approach. Unless you can guarantee that your data won't have any unexpected characters, you should be using SQL parameters at the very least to ensure they are interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that one of your array elements contains an apostrophe.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't encode the string properly to be a string literal in SQL. When there is an apostrophe in the string it will break the syntax.

You should use a parameter instead of concatenating the string into the SQL code.

This will also allow you to reuse the same query and command object for all queries, instead of creating a new command for each query. You can also call `Prepare` on the command before the loop to reduce some of the overhead for each execution.

Example:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  using (SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("server=localhost; uid=xxxx; pwd=xxxx; database=Movies;")) {
    sql.Open();

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [" + folderName + "] values(@P, '')", sql) {

      SqlParameter param = command.Parameters.Add("@P", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
      command.Prepare();

      for (int i = 0; i < jointArray.Length; i++) {
        param.Value = jointArray[i].ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout for the SQL escape characters like `'`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your values you have an unescaped single quote.  Prob something like this should quick fix it.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("insert into [" + folderName + "] " + "values('" + jointArray[i].ToString().Replace("'", "''") +"', '')", sql);
```

**EDIT**
Oops, paste error! Pasted what you had.